# Angularjs, ng-click, how put array of checkbox in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mongodb, checkbox

Form with name and checkbox.

I can put the name in MongoDB but how do I put the value of checkbox in the MongoDB?

**Index.html**

```
<tr>
  <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="film.name"></td> 
  <td><label ng-repeat="role in roles">

   <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.roles" checklist-value="role"> {{role}}
 </label></td>

  <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addFilm()">Add manga</button></td>
</tr>
```

Collection **films**

```
db.films.insert({aome:" lara croft", gender:['action', 'adventure'] })
```

Function **addFilm**

```
$scope.addManga = function() {
       $http.post('/films', $scope.film).success(function(response) {
         })};


$scope.roles = [
    'adventure',
    'action'
  ];

  $scope.user = {
    roles: ['user']
  };
```

I do not know to create a function to receive the value of the checkbox and inserted along with name.

Comment: Where's your backend code? Are you using Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Angular documentation for input[checkbox] at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input[checkbox], and pay particular attention to the `ng-model` content.

Comment: Thanks, how make function to add name and checkbox?

Comment: if you use ng-model, the data is already bound to $scope, and you just grab the checkbox like you grab the other data.  What is your back-end?  How are you getting the data from angular to the server?

Comment: Node.js backend with Express and MongoDB, **Serverj.js** to select data to the server db.films.find(function (err, docs) { res.json(docs); and **controller.js**   $http.get('/films').success(function(response) {
  $scope.mangas = response;

Comment: Sounds awesome.  Are you struggling with the client-side populating of the data or the server-side saving it to mongo?

Comment: Yes. the problem is , I do not know the method of the function insert checkbox value of an array, because the array? I want to create a function to search by genre, so it is easy to search for only "action" after "adventure" , **checkbox** is already filled, just insert the mongodb as array

Comment: With checkbox can insert multi array , example: name: "resident evil" : genre: "Action" , "zombie" , etc.